# conditional changing the source and dimentions of video in javascript

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, conditional-statements

I have this code below:

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
           jwplayer("container").setup({
           flashplayer: "http://test.captive-portal.com/jwplayer/player.swf",
                        file: "http://content.captive-portal.com/files/video/cirque-du-soleil/mob.mp4",
                        image: "http://content.captive-portal.com/files/video/cirque-du-soleil/mob.jpg",
                        height: 285,
                        width: 480,
           });
      </script>
```

The whole page is here (in case you need it): [video page](http://content.captive-portal.com/files/video/cirque-du-soleil/index.html).

**What I'm trying to do is to change the 4 lines: file: (...), image (...), height(...) and width (...) depending of the resolution of the window.** I have managed to do this with css, so styles are applied correctly, but this is javascript and I don't really know how to modify it. I was trying to place 2 similar scripts on one page in divs and hide the small one in case of big screen or hide a big one in case of small screen but it didn't work. Video didn't play. I think this may be caused by some scripts in the flash player file.

Is there any way to set conditions for those 4 lines depending of the screen resolution?
Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Comment: Basically I will use a different file, image and resolution for laptops, and the existing one for mobile devices and other devices with smaller resolution. But I don't know how to change it. For example I will use the file desk.mp4 instead of mob.mp4 + will state a higher resolution for it. The resolution corresponds to the video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those parameters are simply an object.

So you should be able to create that object out of the jwplayer call, and simply pass it in. e.g

```
var params = {};
params.flashplayer = "http://test.captive-portal.com/jwplayer/player.swf";
if(!mobile){ //you need to handle checking for mobile devices
    params.file = "http://content.captive-portal.com/files/video/cirque-du-soleil/desktop.mp4";
    params.image = "http://content.captive-portal.com/files/video/cirque-du-soleil/desktop.jpg";
    params.height = 570;
    params.width = 960;
}else{
    //set params in same way but with mobile settings
}

jwplayer("container").setup(params);
```

If you later want to just resize the player. JwPlayer has a 'resize' function that you can call: `jwplayer.resize(width,height)`

Comment: how can I handle checking for mobile devices? can i isntead of that do it by the resolution? for example if it's wider than 960 I want to use the desktop resolution, if not wider than 960 it will be mobile then. How can I apply it? I have this code and I use it for CSS: http://content.captive-portal.com/pd/body/_js/resolution.js

Comment: You can set the conditional to be based on anything that wokrs for your setup - so could do it based on width - although this may come unstuck when getting the resolution of retina devices. A good example of checking for mobile devices (and specific types of mobile devices), so can be more specific can be found at: http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2011/11/detecting-mobile-devices-with-javascript/ .

Comment: I've done this, not sure is it good, but not working. I may have done something wrong: http://content.captive-portal.com/files/video/cirque-du-soleil/index2.html. Sorry for that, but I'm just a beginner in javascript and dont udnerstand everything yet.

Comment: everything is in lines 48-85

Comment: No problem at all. In the code that you reference. For the mobile check at the link I provided the call to detect mobile is: isMobile.any() , so your line 74 would become: if(!isMobile.any()){    and you still need to call  jwplayer("container").setup(params);    once having created the params (which isn't in your current code). I've copy and pasted your source, and implemented the above in a fiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/H6kgZ/

Comment: thanks very much for your help @CraigBlagg, all working great